# upgrade server php version in Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have to run composer in cpanel terminal to install and host laravel project. But however, it gives this error `This package requires php ^7.2.5 but your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.`

I go `Settings >> MultiPHP Manager` and select my domain and upgrade PHP version to 7.3

I check my PHP version in `~`

```
[myuser@server ~]$ php -v
 PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: May  5 2020 19:25:18)
 Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
 Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
 with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I go to `public_html/www` (where my laravel project is placed)

```
[myuser@server www]$ php -v
PHP 7.3.18 (cli) (built: May 21 2020 03:33:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.18, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I go to server_information under General Information and the PHP version is 5.6,
so my question is

> How to upgrade server PHP version from 5.6 to 7.3

Please note that I don't have root access, and also ApacheEasy4 is also not accessible by my user in Server.

My MultiPHP Manager Image
[image]

Comment: if you have `MultiPHP Manager` then I thought you can change php version too, the change option is available on the right side of the top

Comment: @sta I can change my domain PHP, i've changed it to 7.3.. but not server PHP

Comment: is there any reason your not running composer inside of the projects directory any way?

Comment: @MichaelMano I run composer inside my project directory, but it shows the error `This package requires php ^7.2.5 ...`

Comment: try running `which php` inside of you projects directory, then run `which composer`, now combine them e.g. `/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install`

Comment: @MichaelMano still same error: `which php` gives `/usr/local/bin/php` and `which composer` gives `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer` then I try `/usr/local/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install` inside my project directory and it gives `This package requires php ^7.2.5 but your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Comment: do you have access to WHM ? if yes, use easy apache and only install php 7.3 and after installing it in easy apache, go to your host MultiPHP Manager and set your php version on 7.3 again and test your code. be sure let us known the result

Comment: @AmirAliEsteki No, I don't have WHM credentials.. also I did mention in the question that `I don't have root access, and also ApacheEasy4 is also not accessible by my user in Server.`

Comment: @Vpa sorry for my mistake. can you give a picture from your multiphp manager ?

Comment: @AmirAliEsteki I've updated my question and add a image of MultiPHP Manager

Comment: and in phpversion function it show you the version is 7.x but in composer it is 5.x. right ?

Answer (score 0):

if in "phpversion" function you see the version of php is 7.x, but in composer is 5.x: it's because your server manager has set default php path in its envirnoment variables to php5 folder. so you need to use "/php/version/php composer" instead of "php composer"

example:

```
/usr/bin/local/php/7.3/php composer update
```

for find the path of php binary file, you can use "php --ini" command to see where is "php.ini" location. when you execute this command it tell you the ini configuration file (php.ini) path. actually in the parent of your ini file location is a direction with bin name that its your php binary file location. for example in my server output "php --ini" is:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php72/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php72/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php72/lib/php.conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php72/lib/php.conf.d/10-directadmin.ini,
/usr/local/php72/lib/php.conf.d/50-webapps.ini
```

so is my configuration file (php.ini) path:

> /usr/local/php72/lib

and my php binary file is:

> /usr/local/php72/bin

and my needed command is:

> /usr/local/php72/bin/php composer update

---

*****Note:***** please pay attention don't use "which php". because its show you the global envirnoment value of php path that in your case it has set on php 5.x so you need to call binary file from php 7.x folder. and for do it, you should follow my guide to find your php 7.x binary file path

Comment: `php --ini` gives me `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc`

Comment: when I try `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/composer install` it gives `No such file or directory`

Comment: because you must not searching about /etc/composer. you should search about "BIN" folder and php file. and run /php/.../bin/php composer install. look inside /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/ and find any bin/php file or php binary file

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I got it working like Installing composer inside my directory, and use `composer.phar`

Comment: yeah absolutly you should use /bin/php composer.phar. good luck

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me in CLOUDLINUX 7.9 and cPanel v94.0.4:

/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update

Answer (score 0):

[image: Cpanel server config]

Click on manage on the right and update the server version.