# How to upgrade laravel version on cpanel server?

Tags: laravel, server, version, upgrade

Do we need to remove whole project and reupload the upgraded version of the project . Or if there is a simple procedure to do so?

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095884/upgrade-server-php-version-in-cpanel

Comment: Hi. That might help but my question is not only to upgrade PHP version itself but also upgrading Laravel version from 7 to 8 in cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw I found the answer which I was looking for. Replace the updated composer.json file and ssh into the server and run "composer update". This will just upgrade the version on server. Hope this info might help someone.